# When using CSS Variables (CSS Custom Properties) why is the setting syntax and the getting syntax different?

Tags: css, css-variables

When using CSS Variables (CSS Custom Properties) why is the **setting syntax** and the **getting syntax** different?

If I wish to set a value for `--my-custom-width`, I will use:

```
:root {
  --my-custom-width: 120px;
}
```

And if I wish to get a value for `--my-custom-width`, I will use a `var()` function to retrieve the same value:

```
.my-div {
  width: var(--my-custom-width);
}
```

Why do we not simply write:

```
.my-div {
  width: --my-custom-width;
}
```

Comment: simple answer: it was defined that way. You cannot give a logical reason on why it cannot be the opposite because it could be the case.

Comment: I agree with Temani; the answer appears to be simply 'because the spec says so'.

Comment: @Rounin it's directly equal to 12px. a custom property has a value and the value of `--my-width` is `12px` like the value of `width` is `12px`. From the specification: *Custom properties are ordinary properties, so they can be declared on any element, are resolved with the normal inheritance and cascade rules* .. note the **ordinary**.

Comment: your question is only about decision made around a syntax which has nothing to do with the meaning. You asked why a syntax A was used instead of a syntax B and this is opinion based and a simple decision that was taken by the working group. It's like you are asking why we should end each CSS declaration with `;` or why we need `@` when writing media queries.

Comment: I understand that you regard this as a syntax issue. I am suggesting in my answer below that `var()` is better understood as a real function performing a real task on a real subject.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having been using **CSS Custom Properties** since late 2017, I've finally understood properly what they really are and why the `var()` function is necessary...

They are ***not*** (as they so often appear to be) variables intended to directly represent *CSS values*.

**CSS Custom Properties** are *exactly* what they say they are - they are *new CSS properties* which have not (yet) been assigned values.

---

In CSS, an example of something which really does approximate a variable representing a *value* is `currentColor`.

We see `currentColor` representing a value, here:

```
.my-div {
  border: 1px dashed currentColor;
}
```

---

But **CSS Custom Properties** are not CSS variables which stand in for *values* like `currentColor`, .

Instead, **CSS Custom Properties** are newly invented, named, *null-value-properties*...

... and those newly-invented, named, null-value-properties are completely re-usable. Just like `width`, `height`, `color` etc. they may have values set and reset in different contexts.

**E.g.**

```
/* My custom property is --my-custom-width but I want this
   property to hold different values in different contexts */

.left-two-thirds-of-page {
  --my-custom-width: 120px;
}

.right-third-of-page {
  --my-custom-width: 60px;
}

.my-div {
  width: var(--my-custom-width);
}
```

That's why the `var()` function is necessary - it's not delivering "the custom property" - it's extracting the *value* that custom *property* is currently holding and then delivering that value.

---

## Further Thoughts:

In hindsight, I wonder if the whole *name-value relationship* wouldn't have been a little clearer if **CSS Custom Properties** had been called:

```
CSS Custom Property Names
```

and the corresponding function had been called:

```
value()
```

so the syntax would have been written and read out as:

```
value(--my-custom-property-name)
```

---

By extension we could use the `value()` function (or `var()` function) not just on custom properties but on *any* property.

For instance:

```
width: value(height);
```

Comment: Custom properties is the entire spec; variables are simply one option within that spec. That is to say, the first several lines of this answer seem to attempt to clear up confusion where there is none. Further, `currentColor` is not a CSS variable, it is a [reserved keyword from the CSS Colors spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#currentcolor-def).

Comment: I don't agree at all with this. The var() is not necessary to *extract* the value like you explained. The var() is necessary because we have the fallback feature that allow us to use a default value in case the custom property isn't defined. This is a valid reason to consider the var(). Without this, the Working Group can simply consider the use of custom property with its name because there should be no ambiguity in the syntax since there is nothing else that start with `--`.

Comment: full details here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables you will clearly see that var() is more complex than what you think.

Comment: @Rounin *Are you suggesting that CSS Custom Properties are not CSS Properties at all and that they should really be called CSS Custom Values because they represent values not properties?* --> I never said that. They are properties. I was simply commenting on your description of `var()` where its purpose is more complex than what you described and you cannot proove that using `width: --my-custom-width` at first place is not logical. It could have been the case but the Working Group simply decided something else. That's all. You are trying to give a logical reason to a simple decision

Comment: *However, the var() function performs value extraction from the property* it's called substitution and not extraction and it was defined that way (check the link I shared in the top) and writing `width: --my-custom-width` could make a lot of sense because the only difference between `width: --my-custom-width` and `width: var(--my-custom-width)` and probably `width: (--my-custom-width)` or maybe `width: @--my-custom-width` is a matter of syntax. Anyone could have been used and a choice was made. and as I said, the var has the fallback feature